# Hibernate + Spring = State of the art for a java web application?

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, web-applications, spring-mvc

i have a quite complex web application online for some years now using Struts2 + Hibernate. At the moment i am considering completely rewriting the application using Spring3 and Hibernate4 to be able to offer a REST API. I did some reading and my approach is now very similar to this [Blog entry](http://martinzimmermann1979.wordpress.com/2012/11/11/hibernate-4-x-mit-spring-3-x/) 
The blog entry is written in german so i will list some of the core appoaches:

- Hibernate to access the RDBS and ORM (annotation based)
- Data Access Objects (DAO) to access the persistance layer
- Service classes to encapsulate the business logic using the DAOs
- Data Transfer Objects (DTO) to have a separating layer between Spring and Hibernate
- Spring is used for dependency injection and to realize the controller

Is this a state-of-the-art approach for a web application using java?

Thank you for every hint or pointer and your time :)

Sebastian

Comment: i am working with Spring + JPA , its great...you can work with MyEclipse Bling to work with it , its a spring inbuilt IDE and i dont have an idea with REST , but my web service works perfectly..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to take it further the following are pretty much industry standards:

1. Spring MVC (in combination with Apache Tiles)
2. Spring Security for authentication and authorization
3. Spring AOP if you got any cross cutting concerns (such as logging etc)
4. JMock for writing your unit tests
5. EH Cache for your level 2 cache
6. JQuery and the plethora of JQuery plugins...

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a reasonable architecture, although worth noting:

1. I would write code against JPA, so that I don't tie up to Hibernate so much.
2. DTO layer might not be necessary, most of the time results in over-engineering and bloated code. See this: http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/how_evil_are_actually_data
3. Design your transaction setting around service layer early on. Decide on on whether you are adopting Spring declarative transaction, JTA, or ...

Have fun.